# Ensuring a transaction is confirmed using Web3.py

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I'm writing some python Web3 application on blockchain, and I want to be absolutely sure my transaction is stable in the blockchain.

By going through the Python Web3 library I wondered that no embedded function allow to check how many replications of the block chain have written my transaction.

I'm looking for something like:

```
Count_replica = web3.eth.count_replica('0x_my_transaction_hash')
```

The method will return an integer corresponding on how many nodes have my transaction hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with a Solution hope this one is a not that so bad.

I first went to the Eth [Mainnet list provider](https://chainlist.org/chain/1) Then i took a sample of the most stable RPC server the the best Latency and the overall best score. then simply write a validation function that check on those nodes if my transaction have been written. i take the bett that if my transaction have been written on at least 10 RPC nodes it would be stable.

my code looks like

```
from web3 import Web3    
ListOfValidationNodes=[
        "https://eth.llamarpc.com",
        "https://endpoints.omniatech.io/v1/eth/mainnet/public",
        "https://virginia.rpc.blxrbdn.com",
        "https://uk.rpc.blxrbdn.com",
        "https://ethereum.publicnode.com",
        "https://endpoints.omniatech.io/v1/eth/mainnet/public",
        "https://eth-mainnet.public.blastapi.io",
        "https://eth-mainnet-public.unifra.io",
        "https://ethereum.blockpi.network/v1/rpc/public"
        ]
    ListOfValidationNodesConnect=[Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(i)) for i in ListOfValidationNodes ]
    
    
    
    def MultiNodeValidation(tx_hash):
        connList=[]
        for index,i in  enumerate(ListOfValidationNodesConnect):
            try:
                transact = dict(i.eth.get_transaction(tx_hash))
                connList.append({"nodes":ListOfValidationNodes[index],"valid":True,"BlockNum":transact['blockNumber']})
                
            except:
                # transaction hash was not found on the nodes and return an error
                connList.append({"nodes":ListOfValidationNodes[index],"valid":False,"BlockNum":None})
        return len([x for x in connList if x['valid']==True])==len(connList),connList
```

Would appreciate some feedback :)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa would you be so kind and give me a feedback about my code. I have assumed that all RPC links refred to a different set of nodes but not sure about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The blockchain is a **decentralized network**, and t**ransactions are propagated to multiple nodes for verification and inclusion** in the blockchain. **Once a block is mined, the transactions inside the block are already propagated to all the synced nodes.**

However, in **very rare cases**, **some blocks can be reversed** due to errors or attacks. But, the **more blocks mined after the block containing your transaction, the more difficult it is for that block to be reversed.**

Then you can check for how many blocks were mined after yours:

```
from web3 import Web3

# Connect to Ethereum node
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('<your_ethereum_node_url>'))

# Get transaction receipt
tx_hash = '0x_my_transaction_hash'
tx_receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

if tx_receipt is not None:
    # Get current block number
    current_block_number = web3.eth.blockNumber

    # Get block number of transaction
    block_number = tx_receipt['blockNumber']

    # Calculate number of confirmations
    confirmations = current_block_number - block_number + 1
```

Comment: Blocks are reversed all the time; it is not rare. This is because of lightspeed issues, validator issues and so on. The blockchain tip is effectively unstable. This is the exact reason why you want your transaction to be in a historical block before you consider it final.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa you are talking about orphan (stale) blocks: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/orphan-block-cryptocurrency.asp#:~:text=An%20orphan%20block%20is%20a,the%20shorter%20chain%20are%20orphaned.
Reversed blocks can happen in very rare case, like errors during upgrades or chain attacks

Comment: That is not correct. Minor 1-2 chain reorganisations happen almost daily https://www.google.fi/amp/s/decrypt.co/101390/ethereum-beacon-chain-blockchain-reorg%3famp=1?espv=1

Comment: I can experimentaly confrm that transaction is not sistematically deployed on all the nodes instantaneously. with the code that i write as my own response and also depending on the gas you put in, you can be selected by the minners with more or less priority, some time it took me up to 3 minutes to get my transaction deployed onto all the RPC network i have in "validation"  sample.